# Mongo text index on populated fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Im just learning indexing with Mongoose/MongoDB and I dont know why this isnt working.

this is my schema

```
const timeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    actionId:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    start: {
        type: Date
    },
    end: {
        type: Date
    },
    user:{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'User'},
    task:{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Task'},
    pausedSeconds:{
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }
});

const Time = mongoose.model('Time', timeSchema)
```

i want to have a text index in two populated fields user and task, i created the index this way

```
timeSchema.index({"user.name":"text","task.taskName":"text"})
```

Here is an example of the documents

```
{
            "pausedSeconds": 18,
            "_id": "5db1dde8d5bc93526c26fa38",
            "actionId": "5feaebcf-6b90-45be-8104-452d643472a0",
            "user": {
                "_id": "5d4af77e4b6cbf3dd8c5f3ac",
                "name": "admin"
            },
            "task": {
                "_id": "5d4aff2f61ad755154b8a1c6",
                "taskName": "task 1 updated!"
            },
            "start": "2019-10-24T17:22:48.000Z",
            "end": "2019-10-24T17:30:00.000Z"
        },
```

**I have one issue and one question
The issue is:**

What im trying to do is get all the documents that have "task 1 updated" (for task.taskName) or 
"admin" (for user.name) doing it this way

```
Time.find({ '$text': { '$search': "admin" } })

Time.find({ '$text': { '$search': "task 1 updated" } })
```

but it doesnt seem to work

**The question is:** 
If I want to do a text search for the fields start,end being a Date type or for the field pausedSeconds being a Number type what should I do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: _".Issue: .. but it doesn't seem to work"_: What is not working. Please explain, more. Is there a result and it looks wrong _or_ there is no result at all.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you aren't specifying what property to search on. Do this: `Time.find({taskName: { '$text': { '$search': "admin" }}})`.

Also, I'm not sure if you're just not showing all the code or if you're actually doing your query wrong, but it should be written like this:

```
Time.find({taskName: { '$text': { '$search': "admin" }}}).exec(function(err, times) {
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(times);
});
```